# display icons in p:column filteroptions

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i'm trying to display icons as filterOptions on my p:datatable.
the current situation is that i display a list of unicode symbols , but the client wants them to be colorful.
the code below shows how i fill my list of states (my filter options) in my backingbean.

```
private static final String LABEL_DEACTIVATED = "\u24E7";
private static final String LABEL_ACTIVATED = "\u2714";
private void fillSelectItem() {
        userStates = new SelectItem[3];

        userStates[0] = new SelectItem("", LABEL_ALL);
        userStates[1] = new SelectItem(USER_ACTIVATED.name(), LABEL_ACTIVATED);
        userStates[2] = new SelectItem(USER_DEACTIVATED.name(),
                LABEL_DEACTIVATED);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to style each individual icon, as long as your target browser supports CSS2 attribute selectors (ie. almost all modern browsers). Put the following in your css file:

```
option[value='USER_ACTIVATED'] {
    /* for example */
    background-image: url(.....);
    background-color: #123456;   
    color: #123123;
}

option[value='USER_DEACTIVATED'] {
    /* for example */
    background-image: url(.....);
    background-color: #888111;   
    color: #222222;
}
```

Comment: apearently an html select can only support textual elements , so this won't work i guess . http://jsfiddle.net/xLjCV/

Comment: It works now: [http://jsfiddle.net/HtMqy/](http://jsfiddle.net/HtMqy/) . Unfortunately in my initial example, I used the wrong CSS comments, so the background image rule was ignored. I've edited my answer to be correct. Thanks!

Comment: Note: background images on `option` elements works in Firefox only and not in IE/Chrome.